# iOS 13.6.1 Reminder App No Longer Separates Multiple Lines

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I want to recover the line separation feature of the pre-iOS 9 Reminder App but running on iOS 13.6.1.

With this feature, I could paste multi-line text in a reminder item, and when I would hit Enter, it would the text break up into multiple reminders, one per line.

In this question from 2015, [Reminders no longer separates items by line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208051/reminders-no-longer-separates-items-by-line/399417?noredirect=1#comment552457_399417), user bmike wrote that the behavior is still there but you have to paste the text "into the list itself" instead of in a item. But every time I try that on my iPhone, Reminders creates a new reminder item forcing me to paste into that. User Steve Moser says to do this by long pressing without letting the keyboard show, but when I try that, no menu pops up.

I miss the old reminders app. Not only did it do this multi-line break up, it was also smart about the reminders in a list, keeping them in different orders for the active and completed, where the former was in an order of my choice and the latter was in the order I checked them off.

How do I paste "into the list itself" on an iPhone?

Comment: Are you on iOS 13?

Comment: Yes, iOS 13.6.1